# how to start building a application for positioning system

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to build an small application in android API that will unable me to track the location of my friends using GPS technology.. I want to use OpenStreetMaps for the same, but didnt know from where i can start this project.. please guide me towards the right path..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the Api for the OS Maps at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6

Also, http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aopenstreetmap+label%3aandroid&projectsearch=Search+projects

gives you code of some Android application that implements Open street map.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Cookbook (https://androidcookbook.com/) has a section on mapping including some OpenStreetMap samples (https://androidcookbook.com/ChapterView.seam?chapterId=1000).